# Behavior of Incomplete Gamma function with negative s, as x goes to zero

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, power-series, special-functions, gamma-function

From the second item under the [Asymptotic Behavior section of the Wikipedia article for the incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Asymptotic_behavior), it is written that

$$
\frac{\Gamma(s,x)}{x^s} \to -\frac{1}{s} \text{ as } x \to 0 \text{ and } \Re(s) < 0
$$

where the (upper) incomplete gamma function $\Gamma$ is defined as

$$
\Gamma(s,x) := \int_x^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-t} \,\mathrm{d}t
$$

How do you derive this asymptotic behavior (at least when $s$ is real)? There doesn't seem to be a reference for this statement. Maybe it can be derived from the following statement, also from the Wikipedia article?

> $\Gamma(s,x) \sim \Gamma(s) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{s+n}}{n!(s+n)}$ as an asymptotic series where $x\to0^+$ and $s\neq 0,-1,-2,\dots$

Comment: You could use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: In you last formula, it is not $\sim$ but $=$